# Correct way to develop a python package at same time than application

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm developing an application, it is in an early stage.

At the same time I've started another project that will need some files form the first one, so now the point is to extract that files to a package that I will use from both projects.

Both projects are under git. so "linking" doesn't look a good idea.

The common functions are in an early stage, that means a lot of changes in the near future.

I think that the best solution is to extract common code to a new repository as package but I don't know what is the most productive way to do that.

If I do a package and install it, every change will need an installation, so debugging could be so tedious.

Which is most common or recommended way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this purpose. You include your library inside your main project.

```
git submodule add git@guthub.com:your-library.git
```

This command creates `.gitmodule` with your confuguration and adds `your-library` folder with library's code. You can commit changes to `your-library` just from this new folder.

```
cd your-library
touch new-file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "changes"
git push
```

Also you can pull changes for library

```
cd your-library
git pull
```

Comment: With this schema, when you deploy, the code will be included in the code instead requiring install the "lib" package. It's not what I was looking for but make sense and is very quick to develop with it.